# Mongodb shell aggregate query comparing dates not returning results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I cant spot what the issue here is. This returns nothing

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
{$project:{CreatedAt:"$CreatedAt",Now:"$$NOW",DateFloor:{$add:["$$NOW",-24*60*60000]}}},
{$match:{CreatedAt:{$gte:"$DateFloor"}}}
])
```

But this returns results - substituting DateFloor with actual value

```
db.mycoll.aggregate([
{$project:{CreatedAt:"$CreatedAt",Now:"$$NOW",DateFloor:{$add:["$$NOW",-24*60*60000]}}},
{$match:{CreatedAt:{$gte: ISODate("2020-04-28T23:17:56.547Z")}}}
])
```

Comment: In order to use aggregation expressions in `$match` you need to use `$expr`

Comment: @Pete_ch You should use the aggregation operator [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html) in the case where the query returned nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your query is when you're doing :

```
{$match:{CreatedAt:{$gte:"$DateFloor"}}}
```

You're actually checking for documents where `CreatedAt` field's value to be greater than input string value `"$DateFloor"`, So `$match` is not considering `"$DateFloor"` as another field in the same document rather it's considering it as a string value. So to compare two fields from same document you need to use `$gte` with [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html) (which will let you use aggregation expressions within the query language).

```
{
  $match: {
    {
      $expr: {
        $gte: ["$CreatedAt", "$DateFloor"];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you might get confused when I say `aggregation expressions` & why `$gte` needs to be wrapped inside `$expr` - In your actual query [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/index.html) refers to comparison operator in MongoDB but in this above query [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gte/index.html) refers to aggregation pipeline operator where both technically does the same but which is what needed to compare two fields from same document.